# No Match 404 route render on all routes: react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am implementing [No Match route](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/no-match), it weird that it's being rendered with every specified route and also for non specified ( it should ), so it's rendering all time.

Here is some code to look into: RouterNavigation component that generates `<Route />` using a array passed and at end add one `<Route />` for 404.

```
 <Fragment>
  {RouteConfig.map((route, i) => (
    <Route
      render={({ location }) =>
        route.isProtected ? (
          isAuthenticated ? (
            route.component
          ) : (
            <Redirect
              to={{
                pathname: "/login",
                state: { from: location }
              }}
            />
          )
        ) : (
          route.component
        )
      }
      exact={route.path === "/" ? true : false}
      path={route.path}
      key={i}
    />
  ))}
  <Route
    key={RouteConfig.length}
    path="*"
    render={({ location }) => {
      return (
        <SuspenseContainer>
          <PageNotFound from={location.pathname} />
        </SuspenseContainer>
      );
    }}
  />
</Fragment>
```

Importing my RouterNavigation component in App.tsx code :

```
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <RouterNavigation />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
```

After rendering

[image: react router ui]

[image: react route]

[RouterNavigation Component Code](https://github.com/narendrasinghrathore/todo-app-react/blob/master/src/components/stateless/RouterNavigation/RouterNavigation.tsx)

[App Component Code](https://github.com/narendrasinghrathore/todo-app-react/blob/master/src/App.tsx)

[App url](https://apptodoreact.firebaseapp.com/login)

Update: One thing noticed is, when we create route dynamically, 404 route renders all times, below is the url that contains same example from react-router-dom for 404 route with little refactor ( i.e. by taking Route part and creating a component that renders that, same as we did)

https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-router-no-match-404-8eiv9?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Package json

```
"react": "^16.12.0",
"react-dom": "^16.12.0",
"react-redux": "^7.1.3",
"react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
```

Comment: I am not sure but i think `<Route />` need to be direct children of `<Switch />`.

Comment: @AtinSingh It is direct children, you see from image also, Thanks

Comment: I mean try removing `<Fragment />` and see if it's working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `Fragment` use `Switch`

```
<Switch> 
  //routes go here
  <Route ... /> 
  ...
</Switch>
```

Here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-no-match-404-bn9yg

`Route` needs to be a direct child of `Switch` and `Switch` outside of  `RouterNavigation` is extraneous, so we can remove it:

```
<Router>
  <RouterNavigation />
</Router>
```

edited in the codesanbox above.

Comment: `<Fragment>`shouldn't be the reason as per the documentation it doesn't render any extra node, it just let you to group list of children. As all routes do work,but it also render 404 route with them. Posting answer, thanks for suggestion.

Comment: @NarendraSinghRathore please see my edited answer, hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
   <Router>
    <Switch>
      <RouterNavigation />
    </Switch>
  </Router>
```

which should work, as [`<Fragment>`](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) let you group a list of children without adding extra nodes to the DOM.

Using in same component work

```
<Switch>
  {RouteConfig.map((route, i) => (
    <Route
     render={({ location }) =>
      route.isProtected ? (
      isAuthenticated ? (
         route.component
       ) : (
         <Redirect
           to={{
             pathname: "/login",
             state: { from: location }
           }}
         />
       )
     ) : (
       route.component
     )
   }
   exact={route.path === "/" ? true : false}
   path={route.path}
   key={i}
 />
 ))}
 <Route
  key={RouteConfig.length}
  path="*"
  render={({ location }) => {
   return (
       <SuspenseContainer>
          <PageNotFound from={location.pathname} />
       </SuspenseContainer>
      );
    }}
   />
</Switch>
```